# How to handle multiple levels of one-to-many relationships in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have three models in my laravel 5.3 application with relationships as follow

```
Category:

public function subcategories(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory');
}


Subcategory:

public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}

public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Posts');
}


Post:

public function subcategory(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subcategory');
}
```

Now in my controller I only have a category and I want all the posts (ordered by id) that are in the subcategories which belong to the category I have. Something like:

```
$posts = $category->subcategories->posts;
```

But I don't know how to do that. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hey Ahmed**

What you need is the use of the [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relation:

```
Category:

public function posts(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Posts', 'App\Subcategory');
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$posts = $category->posts;
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks very much.